Prepopulate To Email Address using Global Action
We have a global action to send email.
It populates the to address correctly when invoked from Contact detail page.

We want to use same the global action to send email from Opportunity record.
Here the to address is not getting populated as shown below.

From my search online, I learned that we can use JUNCTIONIDLIST() for this.
I am using the below formula which gives syntax error.
JUNCTIONIDLIST($Contact.Id, $Opportunity.Account.Contact.Id)


Can someone let me know how to fix this formula or suggest me some ideas so that I will be able to prepopulate the underlying contact's email address when the email send global action is invoked from the Opportunity record) ?
